# Where did SVN checkout to?

Tags: svn, location, svn-checkout

I just checked out the source code for `HTTPCore` from [Apache](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/source-repository.html), using

```
svn checkout https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpcomponents/httpcore/tags/4.3.2 httpcomponents-core
```

But I can't figure out where it downloaded it to.

How can I find the location of these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checkout` command will have created a directory called `httpcomponents-core` in the directory you were in when you invoked the command. The files will be in that directory if the checkout was successful.